# show anonymous users in a view

Tags: views, users

I was wondering if there was a method to show anonymous users in a view. I have looked at various alternative such as the link below for showing anonymous users. 
http://scito.ch/content/count-access-statistics-anonymous-users-only-drupal-7.
I did construct a view for the number of registered users but am having a problems showing just anonymous users in a view

Answer (score 2):

There is (and should only ever be) **one** anonymous "user" for your site.  That will be in your db users table as uid 0.

*If* you'd like to count the number of anonymous users that are visiting your site at a certain time you can adapt (to a custom module) something like this that is used in the [admin_menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu/) module (this is from admin_menu.module 7.x.3.0-rc starting around line 395:

```
function admin_menu_get_user_count() {
  $interval   = REQUEST_TIME - variable_get('user_block_seconds_online', 900);
  $count_anon = admin_menu_session_count($interval, TRUE);
  $count_auth = admin_menu_session_count($interval, FALSE);

  return t('@count-anon / @count-auth', array('@count-anon' => $count_anon, '@count-auth' => $count_auth));
}

function admin_menu_session_count($timestamp = 0, $anonymous = TRUE) {
  $query = db_select('sessions');
  $query->addExpression('COUNT(sid)', 'count');
  $query->condition('timestamp', $timestamp, '>=');
  $query->condition('uid', 0, $anonymous ? '=' : '>');
  return $query->execute()->fetchField();
}
```

And then output the return values. If you want to count the all time number of anon visits to your site than that is a different story. If so, please update. Thanks.

Comment: So I can use that code in creating my own module. In That correct. How would I output the results in a view.

Comment: Yes you can, you would have to change the function names to YOUR_MODULE_NAME_get_user_count and YOUR_MODULE_NAME_session_count and then in your view the quick way is to add http://drupal.org/project/views_php and call YOUR_MODULE_NAME_session_count in a php field.  The better way as noted in the views_php module is to " to use regular handlers and plugins when available (or even to create one yourself)".